# Horizontal alignment of multi-line text in a matplotlib text box

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to have multi-line text left-aligned inside a box that is right-aligned, or rather whose position is defined in terms of its right edge.

That is, I'd like the text "the other." in the following to be left-aligned:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def lowerrighttext(ax,text, size=12, alpha = 0.5, color='k', dx=1.0/20, dy=1.0/20):
    return  ax.annotate(text, xy=(1-dx, dy), xycoords = 'axes fraction', 
                        ha='right',va='bottom', color=color, 
                        size=size, bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w", 
                        ec="0.5", alpha=alpha) )

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot([0,1],[0,1])
lowerrighttext(ax,'One line is longer than\nthe other.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If I were to specify `ha='left'` it would apply to the text box, not just the text:
[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on why `ha="left"` isn't what you're looking for?  (Sorry for misunderstanding)

Comment: @jedwards: That does not work for me. I've added another image to show what that does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the trick is the [`multialignment` or `ma`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/text_props.html) named argument:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def lowerrighttext(ax,text, size=12, alpha = 0.5, color='k', dx=1.0/20, dy=1.0/20):
    return ax.annotate(text, xy=(1-dx, dy), xycoords = 'axes fraction',
                        ha='right',va='bottom',ma='left',color=color,           # Here
                        size=size, bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w",
                        ec="0.5", alpha=alpha))

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot([0,1],[0,1])
lowerrighttext(ax,'One line is longer than\nthe other.')
plt.show()
```

Produces:

[image]

(Although it still seems a little off, not equidistant from the bottom and right sides, but maybe that's an effect of the figure being wider than it is tall.)

Comment: Thanks. That's great! Sorry that this now appears to be a Failure to Properly Consult Documentation.

Comment: No worries -- it got me too, my instinct was `ha` like I said in the comments, but I had to fish around to find where I'd done it.